# Microsoft Surface Pro 3 rejects SD Card - installing Python and Spyder on secondary drive

Tags: python, sd-card, microsoft-surface-pro-3

I got redirected from Stackoverflow to you. Maybe someone can help me with my problem:

I am using a Surface pro 3 tablet (Windows 8.1) and would like to learn to program in Python. Unfortunately, my C-drive has no capacity left (approx. 2 GB are free) to install Python, so I am using a SDXC card as second "drive" ([sandisk 256 GB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0758NHWS8)) and installed Python and the Spyder IDE to it.

However, when I code then suddenly Python sends the message "Python has stopped working" and Spyder crashes. Last time this error was so severe, it deleted all data from my sd card... Moreover, from time to time Windows shows the message that the SD Card was not found - then I plug the card in and out and it works for a while.

How can I implement the sd card in a way, that Python/Spyder runs stable and Windows does not crash permanently by not recognizing the sd card?

Is there a possibility to use Python in a browser-based environment (like Rstudio.cloud which comes with an explorer for variables)?

Is there any other way to use Python in case the disk space is insufficient?

Comment: This sounds more like a problem with the tablet/SD card, rather than Python.

Comment: That's the reason why I posted it on Superuser.com ;).